# Parsing Multiple Naming Arguments in a Function using R

Tags: r, function, datatable

**Function**

```
Daily <- function(DF,Roles){

DF <- select(OutputData, (Store.No:Cluster),(Roles:"Total Trading Hours"))

DF$'Roles (Monday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Tuesday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Wednesday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Thursday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Friday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Saturday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Sunday)'<- 0

DF$`Roles (Monday)` <- (DF$`Monday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF$Roles
DF$`Roles (Tuesday)` <- (DF$`Tuesday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF$Roles
DF$`Roles (Wednesday)` <- (DF$`Wednesday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF$Roles
DF$`Roles (Thursday)` <- (DF$`Thursday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF$Roles
DF$`Roles (Friday)` <- (DF$`Friday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF$Roles
DF$`Roles (Saturday)` <- (DF$`Saturday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF$Roles
DF$`Roles (Sunday)` <- (DF$`Sunday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF$Roles

DF <- select(DF,(Store.No:Cluster),Roles,"Roles (Monday)":"Roles (Sunday)")

return(DF)

}
```

**Calling**

```
RoleDailyOutput <- Daily(RoleDailyOutput, "Programmer")
```

**Error**

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Roles (Monday)", value = numeric(0)) : 
 replacement has 0 rows, data has 1432
```

**Issue**

I am trying to parse "Programmer" to replace "Roles" in the function. I think the issue is that I am trying to reference something within quotations and it doesn't like it...How would I get this to work? if that is even the issue. Sorry if its something obvious I am very new to R

Many thanks

Comment: `Roles` (a variable holding a *string*) cannot be used with `$`. Use `*DF[[Roles]]`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this...so the new line should be: `*DF[[Roles]]' (Monday)' <- 0`

Comment: Nope, your use of `DF$Roles` cannot work, replace that. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Roles` is a variable holding a *string*. It appears to work in `select` (I'm surprised, actually), but it will not work with `$`. For that, use `[[`.

```r
colname <- "disp"
mtcars$colname
# NULL
mtcars[[colname]]
#  [1] 160.0 160.0 108.0 258.0 360.0 225.0 360.0 146.7 140.8 167.6 167.6 275.8 275.8 275.8 472.0 460.0 440.0  78.7  75.7
# [20]  71.1 120.1 318.0 304.0 350.0 400.0  79.0 120.3  95.1 351.0 145.0 301.0 121.0
```

Your code, changing all `*DF$Roles` to `*DF[[Roles]]`:

```r
Daily <- function(DF,Roles){

DF <- select(OutputData, (Store.No:Cluster),(Roles:"Total Trading Hours"))

DF$'Roles (Monday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Tuesday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Wednesday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Thursday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Friday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Saturday)' <- 0
DF$'Roles (Sunday)'<- 0

DF$`Roles (Monday)` <- (DF$`Monday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF[[Roles]]
DF$`Roles (Tuesday)` <- (DF$`Tuesday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF[[Roles]]
DF$`Roles (Wednesday)` <- (DF$`Wednesday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF[[Roles]]
DF$`Roles (Thursday)` <- (DF$`Thursday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF[[Roles]]
DF$`Roles (Friday)` <- (DF$`Friday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF[[Roles]]
DF$`Roles (Saturday)` <- (DF$`Saturday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF[[Roles]]
DF$`Roles (Sunday)` <- (DF$`Sunday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading 
Hours`)*DF[[Roles]]

DF <- select(DF,(Store.No:Cluster),Roles,"Roles (Monday)":"Roles (Sunday)")

return(DF)

}
```

I noticed another issue with your function: an argument is `DF` but you immediately overwrite it from `OutputData` (which is not defined, bad practice). Try this instead:

```r
Daily <- function(DF, Roles) {

  # DF <- select(OutputData, (Store.No:Cluster), (Roles:"Total Trading Hours"))
  for (wd in c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")) {
    nm1 <- sprintf("%s (%s)", Roles, wd)
    nm2 <- sprintf("%s Trading Hours", wd)
    DF[[ nm1 ]] <- (DF[[ nm2 ]] / DF$`Total Trading Hours`) * DF[[ Roles ]]
  }

  DF <- select(DF, (Store.No:Cluster), Roles,
               sprintf("%s (Monday)", Roles):sprintf("%s (Sunday)", Roles))
  return(DF)
}
```

Comment: That works! You are right how odd that it works within the 'select' statement...One thing...Is there a way of making the column titles dynamic? At the moment it displays 'Roles (Monday)' but I would want it to change to 'Programmer (Monday)'...depending on what ever is being parsed...Is there a concatenate string function in R like `DF$Roles + ' (Monday)'`

Comment: Change `DF$'Roles (Monday)' <- 0` to `DF[[paste(Roles, "Monday")]] <- 0`. The premise of `$`-vs-`[[` for `Roles` affects all of it (other than `select`, for some reason).

Comment: see my edited answer, it fixes another problem and shortens it.

Comment: I'm having trouble here...if we forget your new code for the moment...the select statement keeps causing a error: ` Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `Roles (Monday)` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: `DF <- select(DF,(Store.No:Cluster),Roles,"Roles (Monday)":"Roles (Sunday)")`

Comment: I have written these: `DF[[paste(Roles, " (Monday)")]] <- 0` and `DF[[paste(Roles, " (Monday)")]] <- (DF$`Monday Trading Hours`/DF$`Total Trading Hours`)*DF[[Roles]]`

Comment: Daisy, all of my help has been speculative. Please provide the output from `dput(head(DF))` (or whatever your real data is named).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222727/discussion-between-daisy-and-r2evans).